# CUDA 7.0, cuSolver example: unresolved inclusion of cudense.h

Tags: c++, cuda, ubuntu-14.04, cusolver

I am going through the [cuSolver example](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#ormqr-example1) in the documentation and getting the following error:

> fatal error: cudense.h: No such file or directory

Compilation and Linking, "make -n":

> nvcc -c -I/usr/local/cuda-7.0/include main.cpp
>
> nvcc -o cusolver_run main.o -L/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64 -lcublas -lcusolver

cudense.h is not found in the include directory, while cublas_v2.h is there.
Is there any way to get this header file?

- Cuda Toolkit 7.0
- Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: That example looks totally broken and probably should be completely ignored

Comment: Yes, unfortunately even the CUDA 7.5RC doc still has various compile errors in this section.  I've added a suggestion to my answer about how to fix the other compile errors.

Comment: Thanks, is the CUDA 7.5RC doc available online or only with the toolkit? Cannot find it.

Comment: only with the toolkit.  They will become available online when the cuda 7.5 goes to "production release" status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CUDA 7 documentation has an error in it in this respect.  This has been fixed in the CUDA 7.5RC documentation, so you may wish to switch to that version instead.

In the meantime, you can fix this particular error by including `cusolverDn.h` instead.

Instead of this:

```
#include <cudense.h>
```

Do this:

```
#include <cusolverDn.h>
```

Even the CUDA 7.5RC doc still has defects in this section.  After making the above change, if you change all instances of `cuds` in that doc/example to `cusolverDn`, I believe that should fix all the compile errors.